# Uploading photo in codeigniter is not work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

Unable to upload photo. PHP gives error You did not select a file to upload. Code in views is as follows

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload_member_photo');?>
                                    <div class="tab_content" id="tab2" style="display: none;">
                                      <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" style="">
                                      <a href="#" onclick="openFileOption();return;"> <div class="one">Upload Photo / Video</div></a>
                                       <a href="#">   <div class="two">Create Photo Album</div></a>
                                       <textarea name="post" placeholder="What's on your mind?" style="margin: 0px; width: 437px; height: 39px; border:1px solid #999"></textarea>
                                       <button type="submit" class="post_button" style="float:right; color:#fff">Post</button>
                                        </div>
                                 </form> 

<script>
function openFileOption()
{
document.getElementById("file1").click();
}
</script>
```

code in Controller is

```
function do_upload_member_photo()
    {       
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['width']  = '150';
        $config['height']  = '150';
        $config['maintain_ration'] =TRUE;
        $config['overwrite']=TRUE;
        $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['file1']['name'][0];;

        if(!file_exists('./uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('user_id')))
        {
            mkdir('./uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 0777);
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you post code examples here, remove any commented-out code, this does not belong here. Keep examples small. I have edited it for you. Also please review and properly indent your code including the HTML. Right now it is barely readable. Also what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->upload->do_upload()` this function by default search for file input with name `userfile` 
however your file input name is `file`

so you need either to change it to `userfile` or pass the file input name as parameter to the upload function `$this->upload->do_upload('file1')`

ref :  [File Upload Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)